# Why the OUTPUT statement while inserting into the table inside the IF clause returns null on second column?

Tags: sql-server, if-statement, command

Here is my "upsert" code:

```
UPDATE LastTicket SET LastTicketNumber=LastTicketNumber+1
    OUTPUT INSERTED.LastTicketNumber WHERE CategoryId='1';

IF @@ROWCOUNT=0 INSERT INTO LastTicket (CategoryId,LastTicketNumber)
    OUTPUT INSERTED.LastTicketNumber VALUES ('1','2')
```

So, when the row exists, it successefully updates, the `OUTPUT` returns the new, incremented LastTicketNumber.

On the other hand, when the row does not exist, the sql server successefully creates it and populates with the data I am passing to `SqlCommand` (1,2). So, it creates the row, but returns `null`. Meaning nothing! Why is that? And why when i replace the "INSERTED.LastTicketNumber" with the "INSERTED.CategoryId" is BEGINS to return not-null, the category id. Why is that? And how to return what I need?

The table has only these two columns and nonclustered primary composite key on both of them.

`(MSSQL 2008)`

Comment: I just ran a test on your code and it works if the rows doesn't exist. I got a 2 as an output

Comment: is your primery column is auto identity

Comment: @Diego did you run the whole code or the just `INSERT INTO` part? Because that part works for me too.

Comment: yes, everythig! If there is nothing to update, it creates a new row and outputs the value 2

Comment: @Diego for me it does not. I tested from code and from sql manager. Is does not return anything when creating, if I want LastTicketNumber. It **does** return the output, if i write INSERTED.CategoryId. However.

Comment: ok, but now you hard-coded 2 as the last ticket number. How do you expect to get the real value?

Comment: It does not return the dyad either. It returns null. In my code, I was trying to pass the parameter, but it fails in the either way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If no row exists in the table, the first time the batch runs it will return two result sets - the first being empty (because there is no row to update) and the second containing the inserted Id.

Perhaps you are seeing the first result set and not the second.

Try the following:

```
DECLARE @t table (LastTicketNumber int)

UPDATE LastTicket SET LastTicketNumber=LastTicketNumber+1
    OUTPUT  INSERTED.LastTicketNumber INTO @t (LastTicketNumber) WHERE CategoryId='1';

IF @@ROWCOUNT=0 INSERT INTO LastTicket (CategoryId,LastTicketNumber)
    OUTPUT INSERTED.LastTicketNumber INTO @t (LastTicketNumber) VALUES ('1','2')

  select LastTicketNumber from @t
```